# How do i use the Google API classes in my website using PHP and javascript?

Tags: php, google-apps-script

---

> var jasonData = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://graph.facebook.com/"+url);
>   var object = Utilities.jsonParse(jasonData.getContentText());

---

Like these Classes i need to include in my code and use it. How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can only use these specific functions in your Apps Script code written on https://script.google.com. If you need to access Google APIs in JavaScript or PHP here are your options:

[Google JavaScript API client](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/)

[Google PHP API Client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/)

Answer (score 0):

Google Apps Script is a server side scripting language just like PHP. You can not mix these two.  PHP already has functions for fetching url (i.e `load(url, options)`) and for parsing json (i.e [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)).

Check [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/funcref.php) for all available functions etc in PHP